# Subscribe Map and Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, model, observable

I am lost with this problem, not finding solution reading the doc or with some AI help.

I don't know how to solve the error Angular is giving me.

I would like to be able to use `data$?: Observable<Sessions>`;

Currently, `data$?: any;` works but I want to link it to my model.

Here is my code:

```
export class Sessions {
        ID!: number;
        title!: string;
        device!: Device;
        browser!: string;
        color!: string;
        smartphone!: boolean;
    }
    export class Device{
        appversion! : string;
        deviceid! : number;
        deviceversion! : number;
        environment! : string;
        os! : string;
    }
```

---

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationService } from '../../services/navigation.service';
import { SessionsService } from 'src/app/services/sessions.service';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SessionsVM } from 'src/app/model/sessions-vm';
import { Sessions} from 'src/app/model/sessions';
import { fadeIn } from '../../helpers/animations'
import { DatabaseService } from 'src/app/services/database.service';
import { observableToBeFn } from 'rxjs/internal/testing/TestScheduler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-creation-page',
  templateUrl: './creation-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./creation-page.component.scss'],
  animations: [fadeIn]
})
export class CreationPageComponent {

  // isConnected: boolean = false;
  isSessionTitle: boolean = false;
  isQRCode: boolean = false;
  creationStarted: boolean = false;
  isNotCreatingNewSession = false;

  sessions$!: Observable<SessionsVM[]>;
  data$?: Observable<Sessions>;

  constructor (private navigationService: NavigationService, private sessionsService: SessionsService, private dataBase : DatabaseService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.navigationService.connectionStatusChanged.subscribe(() => {this.isConnected = this.navigationService.isConnected});
    this.navigationService.isQRCodeStatusChanged.subscribe(() => {this.isQRCode = this.navigationService.isQRCode});
    this.navigationService.isSessionTitleStatusChanged.subscribe(() => {this.isSessionTitle = this.navigationService.isSessionTitle});
    this.navigationService.creationStartedStatusChanged.subscribe(() => {this.creationStarted = this.navigationService.creationStarted});
    this.navigationService.isNotCreatingNewSessionStatusChanged.subscribe(() => {this.isNotCreatingNewSession = this.navigationService.isNotCreatingNewSession});
    this.sessions$ = this.sessionsService.getSession();

    this.dataBase.getSessions().snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c =>
          ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
        )
      )
    ).subscribe(data => {
      this.data$ = data;
      console.log(this.data$);
    });
    
  }

  toRecordingPage() {
    this.navigationService.goToRecordingPage();
  }

  toCreatingNewSession() {
    this.navigationService.startCreatingNewSession();
    this.navigationService.startSessionCreation();
    this.navigationService.writeSessionTitle();
  }
}
```

And the error Angular 13 gives me:

```
Error: src/app/pages/creation-page/creation-page.component.ts:46:7 - error TS2740: Type '{ ID?: number | undefined; title?: string | undefined; device?: Device | undefined; browser?: string | undefined; color?: string | undefined; smartphone?: boolean | undefined; key: string | null; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Sessions>': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 2 more.

46       this.data$ = data;
```

Thank you

Comment: You are giving the type `Observable<Sessions>` to `$data` but then assigning something that doesn't look like an observable: `{ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }`

Comment: @Sleepwalker Yes, but I have no clue how to solve this and giving it the type Observable<Sessions> without an error.

Comment: Well, I don't really understand what you want to do. Right now you aren't assigning an observable so you can't give it that type. Do you want to store the observable you get as a result of piping `map` to `this.dataBase.getSessions().snapshotChanges()` into `$data` ?

Comment: I would like data$ to work like ssessions$!: Observable<SessionsVM[]>; and not be of type any.

Comment: Considering your service function getSession is returning the same data type that you defined in Session try this this.data$ = this.dataBase.getSessions();

Comment: Please share the class `Sessions` and what is `snapshotChanges()` returning

Comment: @TJ96 The class Sessions is just above in my post.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you're trying to assign data passed by observable to the Observable type.
You're doing what I've shown below in simple terms.

```
this.data$: Observable<Sesssions> = data: Sessions
```

If you want to use observables instead of subscribing just assign to the data$ observable.

Comment: I am not sure where to put this. I got new errors.